# "$Error" already populated when starting PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

When I open a new PowerShell session, `$Error` already contains an error message about not finding the `PSReadline` module. PSVersion 5.0.10586.117, Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise [Version 6.1.7601]. Why is this and what should be done about it?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $Error
Import-Module : The specified module 'PSReadline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (PSReadline:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

$env:PSModulePath contains three (3) directories. The first directory does not exist. `PSReadline*` is not found under the other two directories.

```
\\HOMESERVER\USERS\pwatson\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

Comment: What does `$env:PSModulePath` return when you run it in PowerShell?

Comment: You should remove the Windows 10 SDK you have installed and install the current version of the Windows 10 SDK.  `5.0.10586.117` is how I know you have an outdated version of the SDK installed 10586 is Version 1511 & the build number is incorrect on it.  **Yes** I realize you are running Windows 7, and Yes, its important you at least try this suggestion.

Comment: Since `5.0.10586.117` is the PowerShell version. How would I remove the Windows 10 SDK? I see nothing specific about it in the "Programs and Features" UI. Shouldn't I just update PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says:

"was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory."

This means it's trying to import it, but it can't find it.  It can't find it because it's not installed (it should be in "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine").

To install it in PowerShell 5, you can simply run PowerShell 'As Administrator' and use:

`Install-Module -Name PSReadLine`

More info: [How to install the PowerShell console extension PSReadLine](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-console-extension-psreadline/#installing-on-windows-10-with-powershell-5).

Comment: This worked. If PSReadLine is not part of the Microsoft PowerShell kit, how did my system get to where it wanted to load it?